# Importing grayscale image to bufferedimage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

In CSV semicolon file I have saved grayscale values of pixels from my image. I want to import this values into my program as BufferedImage class object. I can but result image is more faded.

There are steps:

```java
    public static BufferedImage loadImageFromCSV(File file) throws Exception {

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;

        //load CSV file data to memory
        List<String> linesFromCsvFile = CSVUtils.parseCSV(file);
        //calculate width and height

        int width = getWidthFromCSVLines(linesFromCsvFile);
        int height = getHeightFromCSVLines(linesFromCsvFile);

        //get values form CSV lines
        Integer[][] pixels = asTwoDimensionalArray(linesFromCsvFile);

        //generate image
        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        for (int y=0; y<height; ++y) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; ++x) {
                int rgb = pixels[y][x] | (pixels[y][x] << 8) | (pixels[y][x] << 16);
                bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb );
            }
        }


        return  bufferedImage;
    }
```

Below on the left side grayscale image and on the right side imported image to my program: 
[image: Example iamges]

CSV file looks ok: https://filebin.net/9mp7nifqu045b48e

Please help

Comment: The problem is most likely that `setRGB(...)` expects samples in sRGB color space, but your data is likely linear gray.

Comment: We can't see the CSV file, can you please post a sample of the first 10 pixels?